# ASP.Net User Authentication via WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing Android App that interact with Asp.Net MVC 5 via WebApi and I have use [ASP Boilerplate Module ZERO](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Overall) . I successful send and receive data in android App, The is issue is how can I login and authenticate user form App using the predefined AccountController functions in webApi? The Boilerplate zero Project for github come this  AccountController

```
  public class AccountController : AbpApiController
{
    public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }

    private readonly LogInManager _logInManager;

    static AccountController()
    {
        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
    }

    public AccountController(LogInManager logInManager)
    {
        _logInManager = logInManager;
        LocalizationSourceName = MisituConsts.LocalizationSourceName;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<AjaxResponse> Authenticate(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        CheckModelState();

        var loginResult = await GetLoginResultAsync(
            loginModel.UsernameOrEmailAddress,
            loginModel.Password,
            loginModel.TenancyName
            );

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(loginResult.Identity, new AuthenticationProperties());

        var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
        ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
        ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

        return new AjaxResponse(OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket));
    }

    private async Task<AbpLoginResult<Tenant, User>> GetLoginResultAsync(string usernameOrEmailAddress, string password, string tenancyName)
    {
        var loginResult = await _logInManager.LoginAsync(usernameOrEmailAddress, password, tenancyName);

        switch (loginResult.Result)
        {
            case AbpLoginResultType.Success:
                return loginResult;
            default:
                throw CreateExceptionForFailedLoginAttempt(loginResult.Result, usernameOrEmailAddress, tenancyName);
        }
    }

    private Exception CreateExceptionForFailedLoginAttempt(AbpLoginResultType result, string usernameOrEmailAddress, string tenancyName)
    {
        switch (result)
        {
            case AbpLoginResultType.Success:
                return new ApplicationException("Don't call this method with a success result!");
            case AbpLoginResultType.InvalidUserNameOrEmailAddress:
            case AbpLoginResultType.InvalidPassword:
                return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), L("InvalidUserNameOrPassword"));
            case AbpLoginResultType.InvalidTenancyName:
                return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), L("ThereIsNoTenantDefinedWithName{0}", tenancyName));
            case AbpLoginResultType.TenantIsNotActive:
                return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), L("TenantIsNotActive", tenancyName));
            case AbpLoginResultType.UserIsNotActive:
                return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), L("UserIsNotActiveAndCanNotLogin", usernameOrEmailAddress));
            case AbpLoginResultType.UserEmailIsNotConfirmed:
                return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), "Your email address is not confirmed. You can not login");
                //TODO: localize message
            default: 
                //Can not fall to default actually. But other result types can be added in the future and we may forget to handle it
                Logger.Warn("Unhandled login fail reason: " + result);
                return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void CheckModelState()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException("Invalid request!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to generate token and then you need to pass, the token to authenticate user.

Comment: To add a bit more info, you will generate a token when a user logs in successfully and the HTTP response from the login will contain the generated token. You send that token with any subsequent requests to authenticate the user. Here is an example http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/09/token-based-authentication-in-webapi.html